# error while returning a value from a for-if loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop, return

[image]

I want to return a value from a for-if statement in java but unfortunately i am not able to do so.
I did try to return a value from inside a if statement from a for loop, but got an error

Comment: We can't do nothing without your code. [edit] and add your code

Comment: What's the error? What's the code? [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Nope, code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

You have `missing return statement` because **every** branch of the code should return something, here in case the array is empty, then you don't do anything of the loop you'll have no return

Then you have put the `else` in the loop, so if the first number **is not** the one loop you for you return `-1` meaning not found.
You need to wait the whole loop before being able to tell that you didn't find it

And that behaviour fix, solves the syntax issue too

```java
public int search(int[] nums, int target){
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++){
        if(nums[i] == target) 
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code (using you image here):
[image: your code]

Even though you have the return inside the IF statement and the ELSE statement, they will only be reached only IF the code gets inside the FOR statement.

What would happen if you call your method with an empty `nums` array? if would skip the for statement and there is NOTHING to return for your method in this case, do you get it?

That's why you need a return outside the for/loop as well, meaning that: `What your method wants to return if reaches this point?`.

If it is a search, for example, you could return -1 outside the FOR/Loop and remove the ELSE statement from inside.

Don't wanna change to much your code, so you clearly see the difference, since you are clearly starting:

```
public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int n = nums.length;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        if (nums[i]==target) {
            return (i);
        }
    }
    
    return (-1);
}
```